# Mark words with special characters

Tags: regex

I have a list of about 1,300 IKEA products - this is an example of some of them:

```
läkt
bigarrå
bekväm
blixt
block
blom
bärbar
bärby
bästis
bådalen
bågvik
```

I'm trying to use a RegEx to mark those which contain "special" characters - e.g. anything other than simple lowercase a to lowercase z - such as:

```
läkt
bigarrå
bekväm
bärbar
bärby
bästis
bådalen
bågvik
```

I tried this one:

```
[^a-z]
```

But it selects all of the words.

I could do it if I were just using PHP, via the `ctype_alnum` function, but here I'm just using the TextPad or NotePad++ text editors.

Is there any way to achieve this using a standard RegEx?

Comment: works just fine in notepad++, maybe you need to update?

Comment: Are you using *Mark all* feature? Try `[^a-z\r\n]`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I tried in Notepad++ 7.2.2 and it still marks all of the lines. @WiktorStribiżew - thanks - your suggestion did the trick in TextPad.

Comment: I added an answer with 2 solutions, one is an improved yours, and another one that looks more like a solution than a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^a-z]` pattern can match a CR or LF symbols and that fact makes it possible for TextPad / Notepad++ to mark *each* line. All you need to do is to to add `\r` and `\n` to the negated character class:

```
[^a-z\r\n]
```

Note that this will work with your specific data only since it matches any char other than lowercase ASCII letters, carriage return CR and line feed LF symbols.

A regex that will match any letter but a lowercase ASCII letter that can be used in Notepad++:

```
(?![a-z])\pL
```

(Note you may also use `(?![a-z])\p{L}`).

Here, `(?![a-z])` restricts the `\pL` pattern that matches any letter so that it could not match any lowercase ASCII letters (note the *Match Case* options must be enabled).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is C#,  but you should get the Ikea

Regex.Match(value.ToString(), "[àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸçÇßØøÅåÆæœ]");

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which language you're using, but here's Javascript.

First, I split the array into an array, then filtered the matching words.

```
`läkt
bigarrå
bekväm
blixt
block
blom
bärbar
bärby
bästis
bådalen
bågvik`.split(`
`).filter(w => /[^a-z]/.test(w))

// => ["läkt", "bigarrå", "bekväm", "bärbar", "bärby", "bästis", "bådalen", "bågvik"]
```